# What does "up" mean in "Up the Terriers"?

Tags: british-english, slang, colloquial-language

I notice the sports writer say “Up the Terriers” for a British football team. What does "up" exactly mean?

> Hull City 0-0 Huddersfield Town
> Town get things going. **Up the Terriers.**

[Twitter](https://twitter.com/htafc/status/1723355978123366866?t=tdj71qzdfYvbJDgMdySUPQ&s=19)

Comment: It's the opposite of ***Down with** the Terriers!* - except the "approving" version makes do with just a single preposition. Be careful not to confuse this idiomatic usage with ***Up yours**!*, which is both negative/disapproving *and* potentially quite coarse (it's short for *Shove it up your ass!*, where "it" is whatever the speaker is vehemently rejecting).

Comment: @FumbleFingers So what does "up" mean in that context? I still don't understand. Does it mean above?

Comment: It's like "Three cheers for the Terriers!" Or "raise them up / send them down".

Comment: up is good, down is bad. I thought ***all*** languages would have that kind of metaphoric reference. That's why we all assume Heaven is "up there" and Hell is *below*. Plus we have ***high ideals*** and ***dirty, low-down snakes,*** etc. And if you're *up and about*, you're definitely ***alive***, which is better than the cop's cry ***Officer down**!* (injured or dead).

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's like **come on, Terriers**, isn't it? Support the Terriers!

Comment: Huddersfield Town is the football team. Their nickname is The Terriers.   "Up the Terriers" is a shout of support for a football team.

Comment: "Come on, Terriers" could mean "I am disappointed in you".

Comment: I know French has, for example, ***A bas** le Roi!* *(**Down** with the King!)*, but I don't know what their encouraging / approving version is.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's allez, as in: Allez les Bleus !

Comment: @BillyKerr I'm wondering what "up" actually means in this context?

Comment: Nyambek: Seriously? You're *still* wondering what "up" means here?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, I would really like to understand the meaning. What's the exact meaning?

Comment: It's a kind of imperative / invocation: ***Let** the Terriers **rise up** [above the competition].* Does your native language not have Up/Down = Good/Bad associations? I don't know how to specify it any more exactly, given this is a metaphoric (not *literal*) usage.

Comment: [Up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/up) can also be a verb. So "Up the Terriers!" can be seen as an imperative to the world at large.

Comment: @Lambie - Aux chiottes le PSG !

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is an idiomatic [british-english](/questions/tagged/british-english) expression of support for a sports team.  It has a meaning something like "I hope the Terriers will rise up and be successful"

I don't see much benefit in a parsing of this idiom, whether this is seen as an adverb or prepostion (or even a verb) doesn't help understand the meaning.

Similarly you can use "down" to show your opposition: "Down with The Magpies!"  "Down with Trump!"

Comment: I'll add, it's kind of regional; I think UK? A US equivalent might be "Go Terriers!"